# Prove $(-\infty,5]$ is not compact set.

Tags: real-analysis

i need help with this exercise.

Prove $(-\infty,5]$ is not compact.

Edit: I prove is closed, and thanks for the users clear my confusion with this question. Thanks

Comment: It actually is closed, so I don't see what you're supposed to do. Maybe you need to show it is not compact?

Comment: It *is* a closed set in the usual topology on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to prove that it is not open?

Comment: Judging by the mention of Heine-Borel, I would guess that the objective is to show that it is not compact.

Comment: Yes @Ian,  wait a moment i edit my quesiton

Comment: @copper.hat sorry i was confuse, i suppose that set is not closed ._. thanks. let me try to prove that

Comment: The set is closed.... ?

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis yeah. but your answer of compact is clear. thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This set is not compact, because consider the open cover consisting of $B(1,p)$ such that $p\in (-\infty,5]$. This cover can be shown to not reduce to a finite subcover. So, the set is not compact.

Note: here my notation for balls is $B(r,q)$, where $q$ is the center point, and $r$ is the radius.

Comment: I think you actually want the cover to be something like $B(5,p)$ where $p \in (0,\infty)$.

Comment: Why does the cover I proposed not work?

Comment: What does a ball of negative radius mean? (Or maybe our notation for balls is different...)

Comment: The balls are all of radius $1$, centered at points $p$. Sorry if this was unclear, I am using Folland's notation.

Comment: Ah, OK, yeah we just have the order of the arguments reversed. Carry on! (I usually write either $B(x,r)$ or $B_r(x)$.)

Comment: I'll note this! Thanks for bringing it up.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_x = (x-1, x+1) \forall x \in \mathbb{Z}$ Then ${A_x}$ forms an open cover of $(-\infty, 5]$ for which every subcover is countably infinite.

Moreover, every $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is compact iff it is closed and bounded, and your set is not bounded below.